# Remove a pattern from a String containing varying alphanumeric

Tags: java

I am getting a String like below:

```
...,{foo.....}","gm:every":["one:varyingalphanumberic193alpha"],"{bar...},....
```

Now, `checking if Pattern exists in the string`, I want to get rid of this pattern - `"gm:every":["one:varyingalphanumberic193alpha"],` so that my string becomes:

```
...,{foo.....}","{bar...},....
```

I tried to follow this - [How to remove a particular pattern from a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478161/how-to-remove-a-particular-pattern-from-a-string-in-java) but in my case the given `pattern can be anywhere in the string` and `also contains varying alpha-numeric characters`. Feeling clueless on how to compile it. Any pointer in this regard, will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `String::replaceAll("\"gm:every\":\[\"one:\w+\"\],", "")`?

Comment: what characters of the part you want to remove are fixed and what part can vary ? You can define a regex to find the parts to remove and replace them by nothing

Comment: `,"gm:every":["one:..."],` are fixed. Also I want to check if that pattern exists or not before removing it.

Comment: I think (?) my comment (a regex) would work

Comment: I don't understand. Is this just a member of the JSON? Find it and remove it.

Comment: Yes its a member of JSON. Find it and remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
String text = "...,{foo.....}\",\"gm:every\":[\"one:varyingalphanumberic193alpha\"],\"{bar...},....";

text = text.replaceAll("\"gm:every\":\\[\"one:[\\s\\S]*],", "");

System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: Works great. But one doubt, what is `\\s\\S` used for?

Comment: In regex, `\s` matches any white-space character & `\S` matches any non-white-space character. So `\s\S` will match any character.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes its a member of JSON

```
import org.json.*;

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
jsonObject.remove("gm:every");

jsonObject.toString();
```

Comment: This is perfectly fine @Rukshan. But as we discussed initially, I have to deal with the String only as it is passed to multiple teams. So every team is handling that String differently. Thanks a lot anyways.